# how to align email body content using SAS

Tags: email, sas, alignment

A table with 100+ records, and just want to send them via an email, but some of the column(s) got mispositioned in the email. the following is what I tried with 4 examples.

```
data claims;
 input unid $1-4 name $6-34 dt : date9.; 
 format dt date9.;
cards;
0001 Thalibu Boaths LLC            01jan2020
0002 Express                       18sep1998
m003 North American Stamping Group 27nov2001 
t03  S & S                         03may1990    
;
run;
ods listing close; 
filename sendmail email  
from="abc@abc.com"
  to=("abc@abc.com" )
subject="test"  ;
data _null_; set claims;
 file sendmail;
 put unid 1-4 name 6-34 dt  #1; 
run;
ods html close;
filename sendmail clear;
```

the result is displayed below, and the column dt got mispositioned:

```
0001 Thalibu Boaths LLC    01JAN2020
0002 Express           18SEP1998
m003 North American Stamping Group27NOV2001
t03 S & S           03MAY1990
```

I want the email body show the same as the table does.

Answer (score 0):

So, at least when I run your code, it does work; you get the `dt` variable starting in column 35.  Not exactly identical as in your input it starts in position 36, but same idea.

However, assuming you're not reading this in [Pine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pine_(email_client)), odds are you're reading it in a proportional font.  Unfortunately, there's no good way to get a plain text email in SAS to render in a particular font - what you'll want to do instead is build it in HTML.

You might be best off simply using `PROC REPORT` or `PROC PRINT`, or even `PROC TABULATE` here; or else you can write the HTML more directly.

See [this paper](https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings10/060-2010.pdf) for some details about how to send HTML emails, or several other similar options.

Comment: the columns(name and dt) in result are not aligned. just wonder if you can help.

Comment: They're definitely aligned when I run that code, except for the fact that spaces aren't fixed-width spaces - that's the point of the answer :)  If you're viewing this in Outlook or Gmail, there's no way to do this in regular plain text email.  You have to use HTML.